# Django Rest Framework permission on a Foreign key item

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-permissions

I have two models that have a relationship like so:

```
class ManuscriptItem(models.Model):
    """Represents a single manuscript's content"""

    author = models.ForeignKey('accounts_api.UserProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=99999999)

    def __str__(self):
        """Django uses when it needs to convert the object to a string"""
        return str(self.id)


class ManuscriptLibrary(models.Model):
    """Represents a single manuscript's library"""

    manuscript = models.OneToOneField(ManuscriptItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bookmarks = models.CharField(max_length=99999999)
    history = models.CharField(max_length=99999999)

    def __str__(self):
        """Django uses when it needs to convert the object to a string"""
        return str(self.manuscript)
```

> I want to only let a ManuscriptItem Author be able to assign a single
>   ManuscriptLibrary to that ManuscriptItem.

**The following are some of what I have attempted without any success:**

```
class PostOwnManuscriptLibrary(permissions.BasePermission):
    """Allow users to update their own manuscripts libraries."""

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.manuscript.author.id == request.user.id
```

> Result: Everyone can write to any ManuscriptItem that they are not an
>   author of.

```
class PostOwnManuscriptLibrary(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        manuscript = ManuscriptLibrary.objects.filter(manuscript__author=request.user.id).exists()
        return manuscript
```

> Results: No one has any permissions, not even authors of their own
>   manuscript.

The relevant API endpoint views are like so:

```
class ManuscriptViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles creating, reading and updating items."""

    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    serializer_class = serializers.ManuscriptItemSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.PostOwnManuscript, IsAuthenticated,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Sets the user profile to the logged in user."""
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the manuscripts
        for the currently authenticated user.
        """
        user = self.request.user
        return models.ManuscriptItem.objects.filter(author=user)


class ManuscriptLibraryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles creating, reading and updating manuscript library."""

    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    serializer_class = serializers.ManuscriptLibrarySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.PostOwnManuscriptLibrary,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the manuscripts settings
        where the manuscript author is the logged in user
        """
        user = self.request.user
        return models.ManuscriptLibrary.objects.filter(manuscript__author=user)
```

Additional information:

I have overwritten my user model and therefore in my settings.py include:

```
# Takes the model and assigns it!
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'profiles_api.UserProfile'
```

Inside my users profile API

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Represents a "user profile" inside our system."""

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        """Used to get a users full name."""

        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Used to get a users short name."""

        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        """Django uses this when it needs to convert the object to a string"""

        return self.email
```

***FIX:***

> Made adjustments as per BearBrown's suggestions, needed to query the
>   right model:

```
class PostOwnManuscriptLibrary(permissions.BasePermission):
    """Allow users to update their own manuscripts libraries."""

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.manuscript.author == request.user

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            manuscript = request.data.get('manuscript')
            print(manuscript)
            instance = ManuscriptItem.objects.get(pk=manuscript)
            return instance.author == request.user
        return True
```

Comment: show your view code please

Comment: updated @BearBrown

Comment: is `request.user` a default Django User model instance?

Comment: did someone who not author can see `ManuscriptItem` or `ManuscriptLibrary`? you filter queryset by current login user, by your code if not author you have to get `404` error

Comment: @SachinKukreja i have this setup in my settings.py: 
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'profiles_api.UserProfile'

Comment: Please add this information to the question.

Comment: @BearBrown users who are not authors cannot see the content

Comment: and how `Everyone can write to any ManuscriptItem` ?

Comment: @BearBrown when i test using Postman, i use the AuthToken of Author ID: 5, to write to ManuscriptItem author ID: 4, and it still writes. I am using an authToken system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can try this:

```
class PostOwnManuscriptLibrary(permissions.BasePermission):
    """Allow users to update their own manuscripts libraries."""

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.manuscript.author == request.user

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            manuscript = request.data.get('manuscript')
            instance = ManuscriptLibrary.objects.get(pk=manuscript)
            return instance.author == request.user
         return True
```

When you done 'POST', take the `manuscript` data from request and invalidate the `ManuscriptLibrary.author` with `request.author`

view

```
class ManuscriptLibraryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles creating, reading and updating manuscript library."""

    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    serializer_class = serializers.ManuscriptLibrarySerializer
    queryset = models.ManuscriptLibrary.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.PostOwnManuscriptLibrary,)
```

Comment: I am able to Post a library to a manuscript but still with an Author who should not be allowed.

Comment: try new version

Comment: I think we are close, this is something i havent tried. also i got this project/manuscripts_api/permissions.py", line 30, in has_permission
    instance = ManuscriptLibrary.objects.get(pk=manuscript). manuscripts_api.models.DoesNotExist: ManuscriptLibrary matching query does not exist. ----I am looking at this now to see